# Getting undefined value while passing hidden value from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a hidden value in JSP.

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedtxn" value="" />
```

And I access the value from servlet.

```
String selectedTxnNo = request.getParameter("selectedtxn");
```

But the value I get in servlet is `undefined`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you show us more html code? Your HTML form and the code where you are assigning value to `selectedtxn`.

Comment: You need some value to be set here `value=""` like this `value="123"`, and try again.

Comment: @Suniel You are not doing anything wrong . as it says you are not defining the value for the hidden field

Comment: Java doesn't have `undefined` (JavaScript does though). Do you mean the value is `null` or that the value is the String "undefined"? There's an absolutely huge difference between the two. Also, can we see the form? How is the value being sent to the server (standard form submission, AJAX, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

your hidden input field is empty  `value=""` thats why you are getting `undefined`.Give some value like `value="test"`

Comment: Yes, I can, and was getting to that; just had to wait after also commenting on the question. If the value of the input is an empty string then I'd expect the value on the server to also be an empty string.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist not about undefined I think he must be getting `null`

Comment: He could be, but that's still not what I'd expect. An input with `value=""` should still result in a request parameter, it just has a value that's an empty string, which is *not* `null`.